# Complete file2 with data from file1

Tags: file, awk, comparison

I have two files with fields separated with tabs:

1. File1 has 13 columns and 90 millions of lines (~5GB). The number of lines of file 1 is always smaller than the number of lines of file2.

```
1   1   27  0   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   false
1   2   33  0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
1   5   84  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   false
1   6   41  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
1   7   8   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   false
```

2. File2 has 2 columns and 100 millions of lines (1.3GB)

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
```

What I want to achieve:

When the pair columns $1/$2 of file2 is identical to the pair columns $1/$2 of file1, I would like to print $1 and $2 from file2 and $3 from file1 into an output file. In addition, if the pair $1/$2 of file2 does not have a match in file1, print $1/$2 in the output and the 3rd column is left empty. Thus, the output keeps the same structure (number of lines) than file2.

If relevant: The pairs $1/$2 are unique in both file1 and 2 and both files are sorted according $1 first and then $2.

Output file:

```
1   1   27
1   2   33
1   3   45
1   4
1   5   84
```

What I have done so far:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR == FNR {a[$1 "\t" $2] = $3; next } { print $0 "\t" a[$1 "\t" $2] }' file1 file2 > output
```

The command runs for few minutes and unexpectedly stop without additional information. When I open the output file, the first 5 to 6x10E6 lines have been correctly processed (I can see the 3rd column that was correctly added) but the rest of the output file does not have a 3rd column. I am running this command on a 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 with 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. Any ideas why the command stops? Thanks for your help.

Comment: please update the question to show a sample from both input files (5 lines from each file should suffice); also update the question to include the size (MBytes) of each file; also confirm that you want to generate a new file of 3 columns (the description first mentions adding to file2 but then shows writing to a 3rd file ... which is it?)

Comment: as to why the program hangs ... I'm guessing you're running out of memory and/or going into some heavy swapping (also related to running out of memory); watching your memory usage (eg, `top`) while running the script should tell you if you're running out of memory

Comment: please also update the question to clarify if columns 1&2 are unique within both files ... otherwise the current code is going to overwrite duplicates

Comment: are the 2 files already sorted by fields 1 & 2?  if so it might be faster, and use relatively little memory, to write a process to emulate a merge join on the 1st two columns

Comment: You don't have `1\t3` in File 1 so the printout `1\t3\t45` is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

I would do something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    {key=$1 FS $2}
    NR==FNR{seen[key]=$3; next}
    key in seen {print key, seen[key]}
' file1 file2
```

Or, since file1 is bigger, reverse which file is held in memory:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    {key=$1 FS $2}
    NR==FNR{seen[key]; next}
    key in seen {print key, $3}
' file2 file1
```

You could also use `join` which will likely handle files much larger than memory. This is BSD join that can use multiple fields for the join:

```
join -1 1 -1 2 -2 1 -2 2 -t $'\t' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3 file1 file2
```

`join` requires the files be sorted, as your example is. If not sorted, you could do:

```
join -1 1 -1 2 -2 1 -2 2 -t $'\t' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3 <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2)
```

Or, if your join can only use a single field, you can temporarily use `' '` as the field separator between field 2 and 3 and set join to use that as the delimiter:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t $' ' -o 1.1,2.2  <(sort -k1n -k2n file2) <(awk '{printf("%s\t%s %s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' file1 | sort -k1n -k2n) | sed 's/[ ]/\t/'
```

Either awk or join prints:

```
1   1   27
1   2   33
1   3   45
1   4   7
1   5   84
```

---

Your comment:

> After additional investigations, the suggested solutions did not worked because my question was not properly asked (my mistake). The suggested solutions printed lines only when matches between pairs ($1/$2) were found between files 1 and 2. Thus, the resulting output file has always the number of lines of file1 (that is always smaller than file2). I want the output file to keep the same structure than file2, as said, the same number of lines (for further comparison). The question was further refined.

If your computer can handle the file sizes:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    {key=$1 FS $2}
    NR==FNR{seen[key]=$3; next}
    {if (key in seen)
        print key, seen[key]
    else
        print key
    }
' file1 file2
```

Otherwise you can filter file1 so only the matches are feed to the awk from file1 and then file2 dictates the final output structure:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    {key=$1 FS $2}
    NR==FNR{seen[key]=$3; next}
    {if (key in seen)
        print key, seen[key]
    else
        print key
    }
' <(join -1 1 -1 2 -2 1 -2 2 -t $'\t' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3 file1 file2) file2
```

If you *still* need something more memory efficient, I would break out `ruby` for a line-by-line solution:

```
ruby -e 'f1=File.open(ARGV[0]); f2=File.open(ARGV[1])
    l1=f1.gets
    f2.each { |l2|
        l1a=l1.chomp.split(/\t/)[0..2].map(&:to_i)
        l2a=l2.chomp.split(/\t/).map(&:to_i)
        while((tst=l1a[0..1]<=>l2a)<0 && !f1.eof?)
            l1=f1.gets
            l1a=l1.chomp.split(/\t/)[0..2].map(&:to_i)
        end
        if tst==0
            l2a << l1a[2]   
        end
        puts l2a.join("\t")
    }
' file1 file2
```

Comment: hmmmm, my `join` (GNU Coreutils v. 8.26) only supports joining on one column; when I run your `join` code I get: `join: incompatible join fields 1, 2` ... did your `join` code really work?

Comment: Yes it did! BSD join

Comment: @markp-fuso: You can get join to use fields 1 and 2 as a single field. [See here](https://tio.run/##ZY7BDoIwEETP7VdMDKaSgLBbjB6MP6IeUCEiBoxt4kH9dmyVkKiH3U3n7Wxnl5tj1xX7YwtFggTPRSrYVeoeaT/L/GwK6aDQ2gm6B79Yi2z2h3nAmZgPGv3RmVhkP9YBK6zK6lwQpByS@jj@T3/Y2/sdlvLUVg1iAiFm3ywCBYW4BU0p4ikDy4lprxZxTW6z5gZva@j0/FZD3S/XqrHlZDQ2Gzs2cKMZRQFFAUeBDp8KnzgPfJ8JvVIcoEyyxjbZ2ER13Qs)

Comment: I tried the `awk` suggestion (version 2; file2 file1)) and the `join` suggestion (version 1 as both files are sorted) and both worked. The difference was the time of completion: 5 times faster with `join` than with `awk`. Thanks both @dawg and @markp-fuso for your precious help.

Comment: After additional investigations, the suggested solutions did not worked because my question was not properly asked (my mistake). The suggested solutions printed lines only when matches between pairs ($1/$2) were found between files 1 and 2. Thus, the resulting output file has always the number of lines of file1 (that is always smaller than file2). I want the output file to keep the same structure than file2, as said, the same number of lines (for further comparison). The question was further refined.

Comment: I tried the first (new) suggestion and it did not worked. The error message was : `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {key=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR{seen[key]=$3; next} {if (key in seen)  print key, seen[key] >>>  else <<<  print key}` I modified it by adding a semi-colom before else `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {key=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR{seen[key]=$3; next} {if (key in seen) print key, seen[key]; else print key}' file 1 file2` and it worked as expected. @dawg, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Final comments regarding the memory used by this edited awk command (see previous comment) with these large files. The awk command produced the expected results and used a bit less than 11GB of memory. The rest of the 32GB physical memory were used by files that are cached (all other applications were closed).  The awk command processed each file in roughly 8 minutes. Work done on an iMac (10.14.6), processor 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 and 32GB 1600 MHz DDR3 memory. Thanks for your help and support that helped me to move on on my project.

Comment: @Opus_francigenum would be curious as to the run time (on your system w/ your actual data file) for my `awk` answer (memory usage should be (effectively) nil)

Answer (score 1):

Issues with OP's current `awk` code:

- testing shows loading `file1` into memory (`a[$1 "\t" $2] = $3`) requires ~290 bytes per entry; for 90 million rows this works out to ~26 GBytes; this amount of memory usage should not be an issue in OP's system (max of 32 GBytes) ... assuming all other processes are not consuming 6+ GBytes; having said that ...
- in the 2nd half of OP's script (ie, `file2` processing) the `print/a[$1 "\t" $2]` will actually create a new array entry if one doesn't already exist (ie, if `file2` key not found in `file1` then create a new array entry); since we know this situation can occur we have to take into consideration the amount of memory required to store an entry from `file2` in the `a[]` array ...
- testing shows loading `file2` into memory (`a[$1 "\t" $2] = $3`) requires ~190 bytes per entry; for 100 million rows this works out to ~19 GBytes; 'course we won't be loading all of `file2` into the `a[]` array so total additional memory will be less than 19 GBytes; then again, we only need to load about 26 million rows (from `file2`) into the `a[]` array to use up another ~5 GBytes (26 million * 190 bytes) to run out of memory
- OP has mentioned that processing 'stops' after generating 5-6 million rows of output; this symptom ('stopped' process) can occur when the system runs out of memory and/or goes into heavy swapping (also a memory issue); with 100 million rows in `file2` and only 5-6 million rows in the output, that leaves 94-95 million rows from `file2` unaccounted for which in turn is considerably more then the 26 million rows it would take to use up the remaining ~5 GBytes of memory ...
- net result: OP's current `awk` script is likely hanging/stopped due to running out of memory
- net result: we need to look at solutions that keep us from running out of memory; better would be solutions that use considerably less memory than the current `awk` code; even better would be solutions that use little (effectively 'no') memory at all ...

---

Assumptions/understandings:

- both input files have already been sorted by the 1st and 2nd columns
- within a given file the combination of the 1st and 2nd columns represents a unique key (ie, there are no duplicate keys in a file)
- all lines from `file2` are to be written to stdout while an optional 3rd column will be derived from `file1` (when the key exists in both files)

General approach for a 'merge join' operation:

- read from both files in parallel
- compare the 1st/2nd columns from both files to determine what to print
- memory usage should be minimal since we never have more than 2 lines (one from each file) loaded in memory

One `awk` idea for implementing a 'merge join' operation:

```
awk -v lookup="file1" '                               # assign awk variable "lookup" the name of the file where we will obtain the optional 3rd column from

function get_lookup() {                               # function to read a new line from the "lookup" file
    rc=getline line < lookup                          # read next line from "lookup" file into variable "line"; rc==1 if successful; rc==0 if reached end of file
    if (rc) split(line,f)                             # if successful (rc==1) then split "line" into array f[]
}

BEGIN  { FS=OFS="\t"                                  # define input/output field delimiters
         get_lookup()                                 # read first line from "lookup" file
       }
       { c3=""                                        # set optional 3rd column to blank

         while (rc) {                                 # while we have a valid line from the "lookup" file look for a matching line ...

                    if ($1< f[1]            ) {                             break }
               else if ($1==f[1] && $2< f[2]) {                             break }
               else if ($1==f[1] && $2==f[2]) { c3= OFS f[3]; get_lookup(); break }

           #   else if ($1==f[1] && $2> f[2]) {               get_lookup()        }
           #   else if ($1> f[1]            ) {               get_lookup()        }
               else                           {               get_lookup()        }
         }

         print $0 c3                                 # print current line plus optional 3rd column
       }
' file2
```

This generates:

```
1       1       27
1       2       33
1       3
1       4
1       5       84
```